# How to run application using wildfly in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, wildfly

I am new to wildfly server. I have successfully integrated wildfly server in my eclipse and able to start it.

But when i am going to Run As from project left click or Add from Server Console in eclipse. It is not showing available project to me.

As those project as not listed so I am not able to run and debug it. While from command line, I am able to make deployment files using gradale and then deployed on wildlfy server and started it.

If some one have any findings on this that will be helpful for me.

Comment: What kind of project did you make? Is it a Maven project?

Comment: Yes it is a maven project.

Comment: I think in the settings of the project itself you can set the server, but I don't usually do that - I run my tests on Wildfly using Arquillian and for deployment I use Maven. So I guess I can't help you much.